# How to display Cut,Copy, select all and share options in actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-edittext, contextual-action-bar

I seen some of the applications like gmail and other apps in which where there's 
an editText and textView while clicking on text long press i can see in the actionbar there's  menu appear say cut, copy, select all ,share and lookup option appears.

This same behavior as a developer wanted to include in my application.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Check this tutorial which will help you to create contextual actionbar

Reference : **[Tutorial : Contextual Action Bar (CAB) - Android](http://www.technotalkative.com/contextual-action-bar-cab-android/)**
Code : **[GitHub : Contextual Action Bar (CAB)](https://github.com/PareshMayani/Contextual-Action-Bar)**

[image]

**Edit**

In your **EditText** layout, add below property to show standard Android contextual menu for copy/paste.

```
android:textIsSelectable.
```

Check [**this tutorial**](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-contextual-action-bar.htm) as well.

Comment: hey ! i referred this link yesterday implemented it shows me only delete option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only copy you can set following tag in your xml of textview

android:textIsSelectable="true"

If you want search ,share options as means you have to create Contextual ActionBar as follows

add following in your activity

```
ActionMode mActionMode;
```

and you have to create an ActionMondeCallback interface

```
class ActionBarCallback implements ActionMode.Callback
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            if(id == R.id.item_delete)
            {
                tv.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"option deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    }
```

where contextual_menu.xml is as follows with required icons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.letschat"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:titleCondensed="Delete">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:titleCondensed="Delete">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_share"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:titleCondensed="Delete">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Now Enable your Contextual ActionBar(CAB) As follows as for example here am are enabling on long click of a textview

```
yourtextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mActionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallback());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

then you have to write your own action on click on each action event on CAB

For Details follow the [link](https://dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab)